# linked list, recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I am working on a program to have a linked list print out in reverse using recursion. My recursion code only seems to print out the last movie, then it stops. "gets" does not work in Microsoft Visual Studio, so I am using compile online's c ide and do not have access to a debugger. Expected output is below. The code is also posted below.

```
Enter first movie title:
Titanic

Enter your rating<0-10>:
5

Enter next movie title:
Inception

Enter your rating<0-10>:
8

Here is the movie list:                                                                                                                                         
Movie: Titanic  Rating: 8                                                                                                                                       
Movie: Inception  Rating: 9                                                                                                                                     
Display list from tail to head:                                                                                                                                 
Here is the movie list:                                                                                                                                         
Movie: Inception Rating : 9
Movie: Titanic   Rating : 8
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Here is the movie list:                                                                                                                                         
Movie: Titanic  Rating: 8                                                                                                                                       
Movie: Inception  Rating: 9                                                                                                                                     
Display list from tail to head:                                                                                                                                 
Here is the movie list:                                                                                                                                         
Movie: Inception Rating : 9
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>      /* has the malloc prototype      */
#include <string.h>      /* has the strcpy prototype      */
#define TSIZE    45      /* size of array to hold title   */

struct film 
{
    char title[TSIZE];
    int rating;
    struct film* next;    /* points to next struct in list */
    struct film* prev;   
};

int main(void)
{
    struct film *head = NULL, *prev, *current, *temp;
    struct film *tail = NULL;
    char input[TSIZE];

    /* Gather  and store information          */
    puts("Enter first movie title:");
    while (gets(input) != NULL && input[0] != '\0')
    {
        current = (struct film *) malloc(sizeof(struct film));  //request a new film struct
        if (head == NULL)       /* first structure       */
            head = current;
        else                    /* subsequent structures */
            prev->next = current;
        current->next = NULL;
        strcpy(current->title, input);
        puts("Enter your rating <0-10>:");
        scanf("%d", &current->rating);
        while (getchar() != '\n')
            continue;
        puts("Enter next movie title (empty line to stop):");
        prev = current;
        tail = current;
    }
    /* Show list of movies                    */
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("No data entered. ");
    else
        printf("Here is the movie list:\n");
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("Movie: %s  Rating: %d\n",
            current->title, current->rating);
        current = current->next;
    }

    puts("Display list from tail to head:");
    if (tail == NULL)
        puts("No data entered.");
    else
        puts("Here is the movie list: ");
    current = tail;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("Movie: %s Rating : %d\n", current->title, current->rating);
        current = current->prev;
    }

    /* Program done, so free allocated memory */
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        temp = current->next;  
        free(current);
        current = temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But there's no recursion in your program, as you claim. (That would require a function that calls itself.)

Comment: ..and you even don't need recursion at all for this problem.

Comment: @MichaelWalz how do I do it without recursion?

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pencil and you'll find out. It's not difficult at all. Hint: google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You're not filling current->prev field in struct here:

```
    if (head == NULL)       /* first structure       */
    {
        head = current;
        current->prev = NULL;
    }
    else                    /* subsequent structures */
    {
        current->prev = prev;
        prev->next = current;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @koper89.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the data member `prev` of the inserted node. You should write for example

```
    if (head == NULL)       /* first structure       */
    {
        head = current;
        current->prev = NULL;
    }
    else                    /* subsequent structures */
    {
        prev->next = current;
        current->prev = tail;
    }
```

Take into account that using the variable `prev` is redundant in this loop.

Also the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard any more. Instead use the function `fgets`.